# How to pass a FormatString as ConverterParameter in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a binding with converter. I want to pass the "#,,.0M" format string as converter parameter.

This xaml in not valid:

```
<local:SalesPerformanceControl FirstSalesVolume="{Binding Path=TodaySalesVolume, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=decimalToFormatedStringConverter}, ConverterParameter=#,,.0M}"/>
```

**Error**:

> The type '' was not found.

How to pass this string correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either use single quotes on the string to be passed:

```
       <local:SalesPerformanceControl FirstSalesVolume="{Binding Path=TodaySalesVolume, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=decimalToFormatedStringConverter}, ConverterParameter='#,,.0M'}"/>
```

OR use elaborate syntax to bind like below:

```
    <local:SalesPerformanceControl>
        <local:SalesPerformanceControl.FirstSalesVolume>
            <Binding Path="TodaySalesVolume" Converter="{StaticResource decimalToFormatedStringConverter}" ConverterParameter="#,,.0M" />
        </local:SalesPerformanceControl.FirstSalesVolume>
    </local:SalesPerformanceControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the way can be declare your string in resources and pass it to your converter.

```
<UserControl.Resources>

 <sys:String x:Name="strParam">#,,.0M</sys:String>

    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Add like as bellow

```
<local:SalesPerformanceControl FirstSalesVolume="{Binding Path=TodaySalesVolume, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=decimalToFormatedStringConverter},   ConverterParameter={StaticResource strParam}}"/>
```

may help you

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the string as a resource.

First add the following *xmlns* declaration

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then save the string in the resources

```
<sys:String x:Key="format">#,,.0M</sys:String>
```

And use it as follows

```
<local:SalesPerformanceControl FirstSalesVolume="{Binding Path=TodaySalesVolume, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=decimalToFormatedStringConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource ResourceKey=format}}"/>
```